# Confusion with typename and therefore errors

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

```
//more code omitted that is not relevant, the IF template is not completely shown here

template <bool condition, typename ThenType, typename ElseType>
    struct IF {
         typedef typename ChooseSelector<condition>::RETURN Selector;
    };

    template <bool condition>
        struct ChooseSelector {
             typedef SelectThen RETURN;
        };

    template <>
        struct ChooseSelector<false> {
             typedef SelectElse RETURN;
        };
//SelectElse and SelectThen omitted
```

I get `Expected nested-name-specifier before ‘ChooseSelector’`.  According to the often linked [C++ typename description](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) and if I get it correctly, `typename` is needed here. If I remove typename from the IF template, I still get the same error, so I am a little confused what is actually causing the error. I read many answers that suggest that removing typename fixes the problem, but that is not the case in this case. What am I missing?

The error comes from g++ on Linux, VS10 throws an error as well.

Comment: Put your IF template after the ChooseSelector template

Comment: Hmm that worked. Wasn't thinkig of that. If you post it as answer, I will accpet it. Can you tell me why this is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your IF template after the ChooseSelector template.

When compiling the IF template, ChooseSelector need to exist as a template, you're using `ChooseSelector<condition>` which is parsed first pass. The `typename` is needed to tell the compiler that `RETURN`, which is fully evaluated on instantiation when specializations are known, should be considered a type for the purpose of first pass.